prove that this set doesn't have density
We define the natural density for a set A like this:
$$d(A)= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{|A\cap \{1,2,...,n\}|}{n}$$
I read that if A is a set that it is all the even numbers in intervals of the shape $[2^{2m},2^{2m+1}] $ doesn't have density.
I suppose to prove that by proving these limits:
$ \lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \dfrac{|A\cap \{1,2,...,2^{2m+2}\}|}{2^{2m+2}}=\frac{1}{6} $
and
$ \lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \dfrac{|A\cap \{1,2,...,2^{2m+1}\}|}{2^{2m+1}}=\frac{1}{3} $
I tried to found that by writing some terms of these sequences like this:
$\left\{\dfrac{|A\cap \{1,2,...,2^{2m+2}\}|}{2^{2m+2}}\right\}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}= (\frac{4}{16},\frac{12}{64},\frac{42}{256},...)$
$\left\{\dfrac{|A\cap \{1,2,...,2^{2m+1}\}|}{2^{2m+1}}\right\}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}= (\frac{3}{8},\frac{12}{32},\frac{45}{128},...)$
But I cannot see how I can find these limits.

Try finding two subsequences going to two different limits.

The interval $I_k=[2^k,2^{k+1}]$ contains exactly $2^{k-1}+1$ even numbers.
The interval $[1,2^n]$ contains $I_k$ for $k\in\{1,n-1\}$.  Note that we only care about $I_k$ when $k$ is even.
Case I:  $n=2m+1$ (the odd case).  In this case we are interested in even $k=2l$ from $2$ to $2m$, so we count the relevant number of elements in $A$ as $$\sum_{l=1}^m(2^{2l-1}+1)=\frac 23\times (2^{2m}-1)+m$$
As the total number of natural numbers between $1$ and $2^{2m+1}$ is, of course, $2^{2m+1}$, we see that the portion that is in $A$ is, ignoring terms which clearly go to $0$ in the limit,  $$\frac 23\times \frac {2^{2m}}{2^{2m+1}}=\frac 13$$
The even case is similar and I'll leave that to the OP.  Or one could simply note that passing from the odd case to the next even case doubles the denominator while leaving the numerator unchanged.

How is $$\sum_{l=1}^m(2^{2l-1}+1)=\frac 23\times (2^{2m}-1)+m$$ I couldn't see it

Well, the $m$ just comes from summing $1$ $m$ times.  For the rest, we consider $S=2+2^3+\cdots +2^{2m-1}$ so $4S=2^3+\cdots +2^{2m+1}=S-2+2^{2m+1}$ from which the claim follows.  Usual geometric series summation.

thank you very much
